# Unexpected EOF in conditional construct in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, syntax, gnu-make

I have the following target in my makefile

```
omp: main_omp.c omp_impl.o
        if [[ ! -e ../bin/ ]]; then mkdir ../bin/ fi
        gcc $(CFLAGS) ... # compilation et cetera
```

On executing `make omp` in the same directory causes make to terminate with the following error

```
if [[ ! -e ../bin ]]; then mkdir ../bin fi
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
make: *** [makefile:10: omp] Error 2
```

Executing the `if ... fi` statement in the terminal works as intended. I tried different combinations of double quotes, splitting into different lines etc and nothing works.

How do I fix this problem? Why is make running into an EOF over here?

Comment: `if ...; then ...; fi` see `help if` for more, Also https://shellcheck.net to validate your script.

Comment: @Jetchisel Thank you for the info, I did not know about shellcheck.net. Your corrections worked. I also had to change `[[ ... ]]` to `[ ... ]`. It works fine after that.

Comment: `[[...]]` is bash syntax.  It's not supported by POSIX standard shell (`sh`).  make will invoke `/bin/sh`, always.  On some systems, `/bin/sh` will actually be bash, just with a different name.  On those systems this construct might "happen" to work.  On other systems, `/bin/sh` will be something like `dash` which aims to be a small, fast, POSIX-conforming shell.  On those systems, this construct will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state:

> Executing the if ... fi statement in the terminal works as intended.

I doubt that. If I cut-and-paste your example, I get a continuation prompt from the shell:

```
if [[ ! -e ../bin/ ]]; then mkdir ../bin/ fi
>
```

And that is logical. Your shell (either via the prompt or via `make`) sees that you want to execute `mkdir` with two arguments `../bin` and `fi`.  The solution is of course to make sure that the shell sees the `fi` as the next "command". To do that, you need to add a `;` before the `fi`.

Comment: Thank you, this makes it very clear. As for executing the the command line, I might have missed the continuation prompt.